# WRF configure on HPC, Not found netcdf.inc

Tags: netcdf

I work in a HPC cluster and I am trying to congigure WRF, but I get the error

```
Error : Not found mnt/.../intel-19.0.5.281/netcdf-c-4.7.4-fwuuikr7vpuygiz6cqnw7sxyvpzvvcdv/include/netcdf.inc
```

Indeed, the file netcdf.inc is not located in the specified position.
The version of wrf is 4.5.2.